# Поиск максимальных элементов за один LINQ-запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Учусь работать с LINQ. Никак не могу собрать конструкцию. Суть вот в чем:

Есть некоторый класс `Cell` с полями `double weight, int i, int j`.

Есть список `List<Cell> cellsList`.

Есть метод `double getDistanceBetweenCells(Cell cell1, Cell cell2)`.

Мне нужно написать запрос, который будет выбирать ячейки с максимальным значением веса и на максимальной дистанции от некоторой `Cell targetCell`.

Сейчас у меня получилось следующее:

```
int maxWeight = cellsList.Max(t => t.W);

var cells = from c in cellsList
            where c.W == maxWeight
            select new
            {
                cell = c,
                distance = getDistanceBetweenCells(c, cellFrom)
            };
```

Я, конечно, могу сейчас еще одним действием свалить `cells.ToList()` и оттуда выбрать ячейки, у которых `distance==cells.ToList().Max(distance)`, но хотелось бы одним запросом все это проделать. Пытался сделать с `into`, но после выгрузки первого получившегося запроса во временную таблицу, с ней дальше никаких действий не предлагается.

Comment: *который будет выбирать ячейки с максимальным значением веса и на максимальной дистанции* — а такие точно есть? Ну и да, придется материализовать запрос, т.к. `getDistanceBetweenCells` может выполняться только на клиенте. Или у вас и так коллекция на клиенте? Что за странная метка [sql-linq] на вопросе?

Comment: чтобы не выпал Exception `int maxWeight = cellsList.Max(t => (int?)t.W) ?? 0;` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/max-or-default

Comment: Что такое cellFrom? Это и есть targetCell?

Comment: sql-linq пометил, потому что думал, что именно этим и занимаюсь. Все выполняется на клиенте - слоев нет. Тестовая задача. CellFrom и TargetCell одно и то же. Прошу прощения. К 8 утра немного поехал и не заменил когда собирал пример из кусков кода. 

По поводу Exception - есть ли смысл его прописывать, если вариантов его возникновения нет(предыдущий код содержит соответствующие проверки или не отработает, если в текущем выпадет Exception)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете написать один мега запрос, который будет работать и который не каждый разработчик, что будет ваш код читать, поймет. А можете написать 2 маленьких простейших запроса которые поймет и ребенок.

Как пример: 
2 простых запроса

```
IEnumerable<Cell> MaxWeightAndDistance(IEnumerable<Cell> cells, Cell target)
{
    if (!cells.Any()) return Enumerable.Empty<Cell>();

    var maxCell = cells
            .OrderByDescending(x => getDistanceBetweenCells(x, target))
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Weight).First();

    var maxCells = cells.Where(x => getDistanceBetweenCells(x, target) == getDistanceBetweenCells(maxCell, target))
                    .Where(x => x.Weight == maxCell.Weight);

    return maxCells;
}
```

Один сложный запрос

```
IEnumerable<Cell> MaxWeightAndDistance(IEnumerable<Cell> cells, Cell target)
{
    var maxCells = cells
        .GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(getDistanceBetweenCells(x, target), x.Weight))
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Key.Item1)
        .ThenByDescending(x=>x.Key.Item2)
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Cell>();  

    return maxCells;
}
```

Comment: А теперь почитаем вопрос и поймем, что автор просит одним запросом.

Comment: @Exodium Ну, у нас есть конечно специальная дисциплина для адских linq-однострочников и tym32167 не раз в ней участвовал, но тут я считаю действительно нет смысла специально упражняться в мозголомных запросах, нужно показать/научить самим принципам.

Comment: @Exodium добавил вариант с одним запросом

Comment: @AK спасибо, да, я как раз за принципы :)

Comment: Этот ответ является правильным и лучше других тянет на галку.

Comment: Автор же ищет максимальный вес, а не расстояние...

Comment: @PavelMayorov `ячейки с максимальным значением веса и на максимальной дистанции`

Comment: Да, всегда сам стараюсь сделать проще. Даже однострочные функции с одним return стараюсь прописать с созданием переменной и возвращением ее, а не огромной формулы. Просто тут был принципиальный вопрос, как сделать это одним запросом. С кортежами, конечно, красиво, но FirstOrDefault разве не одно значение возвращает?

Comment: +1, но лично мне второй вариант кажется более удобным как для чтения так и для модификации. На вкус и цвет, конечно. Я бы и return в одну строку написал, переменная ничего не добавляет к названию метода. Бонус: второй метод только один раз пробегает по списку и только один раз считает расстояния.

Comment: @Turgor я сначала группирую данные, потом выбираю группы с наибольшим расстоянием, из них выбираю группу (она может быть только одна) с наибольшим весом. То есть в итоге `FirstOrDefault` выбирает группу ячеек, у которых максимальное расстояние и среди ячеек с таким расстоянием - максимальный вес. И эту группу я возвращаю из функции

Comment: @defaultlocale  в первом варианте происходит 2 сортировки (так как они вложенные, думаю работают обе и сортирует за NLog(N)). После чего из коллекции берутся конкретные элементы, на несортированной коллекции это будет линейное время. В итоге 1 вариант - O(N) = NLog(N) + N -приблизительно. Второй вариант производит группировку, которая, как минимум, линейная операция N, после чего сортировку, которая как минимум MLogM, где M - Количество групп. В итоге второй вариант как минимум  O(N,M) = MLog(M) + N. В итоге в худшем случае варианты одинаковые, в среднем вариант 2 по идее побыстрее.

Comment: @defaultlocale Хотя в общем случае, если говорить о производительности алгоритмов, но это точно не о Linq :)

Comment: Теперь понял. Спасибо за ответы, вы меня выручили и прокачали.

Comment: @Turgor пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
var targetCellList=  cellsList.Select(x=> new {Cell=x, Weight=x.Weight, Distance =getDistanceBetweenCells(x,cellFrom)})
    .OrderBy(i=>i.Distance)
    .ThenBy(i=>i.Weight)
    .GroupBy(x=> new {x.Distance, x.Weight})
    .Last()      
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ваш ответ рассчитан на то, что будет только один-единственный элемент с максимальным весом (и максимальной дистанцией). У автора написано "выбирать ячейки", а не "выбрать ячейку". Строго говоря и в моём ответе я не довёл до конца формулу (я нашёл ячейки с максимальным весом - и дальше надо было считать ячейки с максимальной дистанцией), так что формально до галки не дотянули оба. У меня правда более подробно показан ход мысли.

Comment: @AK подправил, поидее должно выдать коллекцию того, чего нужно

Comment: Ну, [во-первых](http://blog-mlm.ru/korotkij-anekdot-s-glubokim-smyslom/), оно не компилируется.

Comment: Так тоже не скомпилируется.

Comment: Вы вернулись к ошибке, которая уже была: не получится скомпилировать `.SelectMany(g=>g)`: вы получите CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Вот теперь правильно. Вернул плюсик.

Comment: Разве строка Last() не вернет нам одно значение? Мне нужны все ячейки с максимальным весом и дистанцией. Если я не путаю, то такой запрос получит сверху отсортированного списка один элемент и преобразует его к списку с одним элементом. Или я не прав?

Comment: `.Last()` вернет `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>`, где в качестве значения будет коллекция `IEnumerable<TValue>`. В ней будут элементы c `Cell` максимальные по Distance и Weight, т.к. именно по этим двум полям шла группировка. Количество элементов в `IEnumerable<TValue>`не обязательно должно быть равно 1, оно может быть произвольным, в зависимости от того, сколько Cell имели одинаково максимальный Distance и Weight. `.ToList()` для `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>` преобразует внутреннюю `IEnumerable<TValue>` к `List`.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался. Пойду пробовать.